# Add button to itemTpl sencha touch

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I am new for sencha touch. I got a question.How can I add button and fire the even to item template?Please guild me solution

Here is my coding

```
     Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.CouponList', {
        extend: 'Ext..DataView',
        xtype: 'couponlistcard',
        requires: [
            'Ext.field.Select',
            'Ext.field.Search',
            'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail',
             'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh'

        ],
        config: {

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: 'vertical',

             store : { xclass : 'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList'},
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: true,
             autoLoad: false,
           disclosure: true,
           cls:'customHeader',

            id :'memberlist',
            items: [
                {



                }

            ],
            emptyText: '<p class="no-search-results">No member record found matching that search</p>',
            itemTpl: Ext.create(
                'Ext.XTemplate',

   '<div style="float:left;width=33%;margin:2px;"><div class="demo-weather">',
                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                '<div class="day">',
                                    '<div class="date">{memberId}</div>',
                                    '<tpl for="weatherIconUrl">',
                                        '<img src="{value}">',
                                    '</tpl>',
                                    '<span class="temp">{memberId}&deg;<span class="temp_low">{memberId}&deg;</span></span>',
                                    'button here?????'
                                '</div>',
                            '</tpl>',
                        '</div></div>'





            ),



        },


    });
```

Btw i am using MVC model.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List templates are not designed to use components, however you should be able to use them in dataviews. Another method is to add a div for the button to your template, and then using member functions on the template you can create and render a button to the div.